# tk_messageBox is showing erroneous display in grid view, but ok in pack

Tags: grid, tcl, tk-toolkit, toplevel, tkmessagebox

I am trying to display a message box in TCL/TK and it is expected to be closed to perform any operation in parent window. When I execute the below code, the text box is going to the "disabled" state even after clearing the message box.

```
wm title . "Message Box Demo"

tk::text .t0

grid .t0 -column 0 -row 1 -columnspan 2

tk_messageBox -type okcancel  -message "Press Ok to confirm" \
    -title "Update V 3.6" -icon "info"
```

If I introduce TopLevel to include "parent' window in messageBox, it is opening a new window as top-level window and allowing to access the text box.

```
wm title . "Message Box Demo"

toplevel .top1
tk::text .t0

grid .t0 -column 0 -row 1 -columnspan 2

tk_messageBox -type okcancel -parent .top1 -message "Press Ok to confirm" \
    -title "Update V 3.6" -icon "info"
```

can someone help me to identify what is wrong here?

Comment: Unable to recreate.  In both cases, tk_messageBox does a grab and prevents access to the other window.

Comment: @BradLanam, Maybe OS-app compatibility? I am using Komodo in Windows.

Comment: @BradLanam, Yes there seems to be a difference in behavior. But the second code script (with parent command) opens up an empty "top1" window even in Linux. Can you please advise how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated on windows.  This does appear to be a bug and I have opened a ticket for it.

You can do:

```
 toplevel .top1
 wm withdraw .top1
```

to hide the .top1 window.

Comment: Thanks for that... that's a nice workaround. I would like to keep the control in the message box until a selection is done. Is it possible?

Because if the user selects the window screen, the dialog box disappears and there is no way to bring the message box if its going to be a full screen.